# No puedo pasar un Object por AJAX a una Function de Visual Basic

Tags: ajax, vb.net, webforms

Tengo un gran problema con Ajax MVC y Visual Basic: Cuando creo un objeto en javascript para hacer un POST en Controller todo bien por cuando recibo el Objeto en el ActionResult, todos los atributos son Nulls.

Puede ayudarme alguien ?

**Ajax Codigo:**

```
    // #region Crear o Actualizar un Item
    function CreateUpdate() {
        var checkBanderas = true;
        var MyObject = {};
        var PasswordRepeat = null;
        // Id Name Description NameOrIP Enabled Default
        if ($('#hdUserId').val() == "") { MyObject.Id = 0; } else { MyObject.Id = $('#hdUserId').val(); }

        if ($('#txt_UserName').val() == "") { MyObject.UserName = null; } else { MyObject.UserName = $('#txt_UserName').val(); }
        if ($('#txt_Password').val() == "") { MyObject.Password = null; } else { MyObject.Password = $('#txt_Password').val(); }
        if ($('#txt_PasswordRepeat').val() == "") { PasswordRepeat == null; } else { PasswordRepeat = $('#txt_PasswordRepeat').val(); }
        if ($('#txt_FirstName').val() == "") { MyObject.FirstName = null; } else { MyObject.FirstName = $('#txt_FirstName').val(); }
        if ($('#txt_LastName').val() == "") { MyObject.LastName = null; } else { MyObject.LastName = $('#txt_LastName').val(); }
        if (MyObject.FirstName == null) {
            $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('hide');
            ShowMessageBox("Error de Validación", "Ingresa el Nombre para poder continuar.", false, " $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('show'); FocusTextBox('#txt_FirstName');", null);
            return;
        }
        if (MyObject.LastName == null) {
            $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('hide');
            ShowMessageBox("Error de Validación", "Ingresa el Apellido para poder continuar.", false, " $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('show'); FocusTextBox('#txt_LastName');", null);
            return;
        }
        if (MyObject.Password == null) {
            $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('hide');
            ShowMessageBox("Error de Validación", "Ingresa la Contraseña para poder continuar.", false, " $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('show'); FocusTextBox('#txt_Password');", null);
            return;
        }
        if (PasswordRepeat == null) {
            $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('hide');
            ShowMessageBox("Error de Validación", "Ingresa la Contraseña de Confirmación para poder continuar.", false, " $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('show'); FocusTextBox('#txt_PasswordRepeat');", null);
            return;
        }
        if (MyObject.Password != PasswordRepeat) {
            $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('hide');
            ShowMessageBox("Error de Validación", "Las contraseñas no coinciden.", false, " $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('show'); CleanPasswords();", null);
            return;
        }
        if (MyObject.UserName == null) {
            $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('hide');
            ShowMessageBox("Error de Validación", "Ingresa el Nombre de Usuario para poder continuar.", false, " $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('show'); FocusTextBox('#txt_UserName');", null);
            return;
        }
        var data = MyObject;
        console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '/Users/CreateUpdate_Users'
                    , type: "POST"
                    , data: JSON.stringify(data)
                    , dataType: "json"
                    , contentType: 'application/json'
                })
                .done(function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        ShowMessageBox("Guardado", "Los datos han sido guardados correctamente.", false, null, null);
                        DoSearch();
                        //oTable.DataTable();
                    }
                    else {
                        ShowMessageBox("Error", "A ocurrido un error al intentar guardar los datos. Contacte al Administrador del Sistema.", false, "$('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('show');", null);
                    }
                    //HideLoading();
                })
                .fail(function (e) {
                    alert("Error: " + e.status + ": " + e.statusText, + "[" + e.Message + "]");
                    //HideLoading();
                });

        //ShowLoading();
        $('#dlgCreateUpdate').modal('hide');
    }
    // #endregion
```

**Codigo del Controller**

```
    <HttpPost()>
    Function CreateUpdate_Users(MyObject As Entities.ApiUser) As ActionResult
        Dim Success As Boolean = True
        Dim Message As String = String.Empty
        Dim model As UserModels = New UserModels()
        Try
            Using logic As Logic = New Logic()
                Dim ToSave As Entities.ApiUser = New Entities.ApiUser()
                If (MyObject.Id > 0) Then
                    MyObject.Id = Nothing
                End If
                model.Item = logic.Save_Users(MyObject)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Success = False
            Message = ex.Message
        End Try
        Dim c As Object = New With {.success = Success, .message = Message}
        Dim r As JsonResult = Json(c, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        Return r
    End Function

End Class
```

Testing Images:

Debug:
[image: Values in a object Javascript]
[image: ActionResult in Controller]

Comment: Saludos Maximiliano, ¿Podrías agregar el controlador (GET) de donde llama la vista que muestras, por favor?

Comment: Creo que sé por qué falla, agrega el GET que lama a esa vista :D

Comment: Tengo un Index, con 2 partialview, el createUpdate es simplemente un action para hacer un post. el GET es index()

Comment: ¿Le pasas algún Model/ ViewModel? De ser cierto, ¿Qué nombre tiene esa variable?

Comment: @fredyfx Podemos verlo en otro lado asi lo solucionamos sin hacer spam? La idea es que le paso un Objeto con sus atributos y en el controller recibo dichos atributos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN!!!!!!**

Para poder pasar un objeto desde ajax webForm a la **Function** y que los atributos Acepten Valores Nullables.

**Clase a Usar**

```
Public Class Testing
    Property Id As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Property Name As String
End Class
```

**Función a Usar**

```
  <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function CreateUpdate(Item As Testing) As Entities.ApiForm
    Dim form As Entities.ApiForm = New Entities.ApiForm()
    Dim flag As Boolean = False
    Return form
End Function
```

**Como ejecutar el Ajax**

***IMPORTANTE***

El Objeto que vamos a pasar "Item" Tiene que ser exactamente **IGUAL** el nombre al **Parametro** que espera la Function y el objeto se pasa exactamente igual a como esta puesto aqui:

**data: '{"Item":' + JSON.stringify(Item) + '}',**

```
var Item = { Id: null }

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ApiEnviromentEditForms.aspx/CreateUpdate",
            data: '{"Item":' + JSON.stringify(Item) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response)
            {

                }
                HideLoading();
                $('#modalCreateUpdate').modal('hide');
                swal(
                'Guardado!',
                'El Formulario ha sido guardado con exito.',
                'success'
                )
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.d);
                HideLoading();
            }
        });
```

Prueba

**Aclaración**: El parametro aqui es pData porque ya es version Final.

[image: Muestra de que funciona]